# Cycles wont do the amount of samples I put in at min samples

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I don't know what I changed but I've been trying to change my settings to get less noise and a faster render, but now it wont do the amount of samples I want it to. 1 sample takes as long as 1000 samples and has 0 difference in noise.

[image]

Comment: Might be the Min samples option, anway quick way to find out whats wrong would be to make a new scene and have a look at the default render settings, and exchange them until you find the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Adaptive Sampling*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#adaptive-sampling) *min samples* is not the actual amount of samples that cycles is using to render the scene.

From the manual:

> **Min Samples**
>
> The minimum number of samples a pixel receives before adaptive
> sampling is applied. When set to 0 (default), it is automatically set
> to the square root of the total (max) sample count.

---

So, what is happening in your case, is that your scene is set to render at 128 samples (the default until changed), so changing the adaptive samples to a higher setting doesn't change anything. If you raise the sampling to something more like 500, you will see a difference.

[image]